# Blur a specific portion of an HTML img element strictly via CSS (or JS + SVG)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

Say we have a single image tag, and we need to blur a specific part of it (for example, for censorship purposes). In the example, we'll say our target image is `100px` by `100px`, and we want to censor the rectangle at `x=25`, `y=40` with `width=20`, `height=35`. How can this be done using CSS?

This is straightforward if you have a parent container, as you can simply render an offset portion of the same image, with a `clip` or a `backdrop-filter` applied. However, this is not reliable for my use case, as I cannot guarantee the positioning attributes of the parent and the image itself, so I may not be positioning the element correctly.

```html
<div id="parent">
  <img src="/path/to/img.png">
  <!-- This -->
  <img 
    id="blurred" 
    src="/path/to/img.png"
    style="clip: rect(25, 40, 20, 35); filter: blur(8px);"
  />
  <!-- Or this -->
  <div style="left: 25px; top: 40px; width: 20px; height: 35px; backdrop-filter: blur(8px);" />
</div>
```

On the other hand, if you just have the image, with no access to the parent, CSS might be the only way. There is `clip-path` and `mask`.

With `clip-path`, you're removing everything **outside** the path, but we want to do the opposite by blurring everything **inside** the path. You can finesse the path clip the target "portion" while leaving the remainder of the image, but this doesn't seem to support the filter, you're left with an empty white block where you want your blur to be (I haven't had much luck figuring out how to apply the blur here). While this achieves the censorship purpose, it doesn't achieve the UX desired with a blur.

```html
<!-- Reference SVG clip path -->
<svg height="100%" width="100%" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clip">
      <path d="M 0,0 l 100,0 0,100 -100,0 Z M 25,40 l 20,0 0,35 -20,0 Z" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>

<!-- Clipped image -->
<img src="/path/to/img.png" style="clip-path: url(#clip);" />
```

A `mask` has a similar constraint, as we are drawing the image through the mask, which means that we can create a `mask` of the filtered and blurred parts of the image, and "draw those through the `mask`" onto the target image. However, this more or less defeats the purpose, as we need to re-render the image in the SVG tag separately, and is brittle if the user resizes the page / image, for example.

Appreciate any suggestions. This has had me stumped for a few days now.

Comment: While you can do it in the front end the user would be able to find the original image so there doesn’t seem to be any point. Have I misunderstood?

Comment: @AHaworth it is fine if the user can find the original image as there is no way around that. Security and truly hiding the image is not the concern, rather, user experience such that for one reason or another, we can blur one or more subregions of the image via some combination of CSS, JS, and or SVG.

Comment: If you can render the image in a `<figure>` (which is not bad for accessibility) then you could use an `::after` pseudo-element to blur the image portion you want to conceal by just using css... 

Comment: @Boguz That's a great suggestion, though a primary challenge here is that I don't have control over how the image is initially rendered, I can only identify that it is on the page.

Comment: How much do you know about the sizing of the image? eg could it be cover, contain, clipped, stretched…. I don’t think this blurring or covering can be done reliably if the image can be used in ways you don’t know. And in any case if it’s for confidentiality blurring it in the front end is not a viable solution. The image needs to be doctored beforehand.

Comment: @jacksongravesWhy don't you have control over how the image is rendered? If you just have an `img` on the page, and you can't control that, maybe you can wrap it on a `figure` tag using js when the page loads